# Reading In Multiple Values from User using Scanf Assembly ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I was wondering how one would go about taking in multiple inputs from the user using scanf. I am going through the book Raspbian Beginners and it does not mention how to accomplish this. Here is my code. If I echo out R2, I receive the value I entered, though when I echo out R1, I receive a random value. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.data
string: .asciz "Hours: %d. PayRate: %d"
prompt1: .asciz "Enter pay rate.\n"
prompt2: .asciz "Enter hours.\n"
scantype: .asciz "%d"
hours: .word 0
payrate: .word 0

.text
.global main
main:
        push {LR}

        ldr r0, addr_prompt1    /*First param of printf */
        bl printf               /*call printf */

        ldr r0, addr_scantype   /* First param of scanf*/
        ldr r1,addr_hours       /*Loading address in memory into register as second param*/
        bl scanf
        ldr r1,addr_hours
        ldr r1,[r1]

        ldr r0, addr_prompt2
        bl printf

        ldr r0, addr_scantype
        ldr r1, addr_payrate
        bl scanf
        ldr r1,addr_payrate
        ldr r2,[r1]

        mov r0,r1

        pop {PC}
        mov pc,lr


addr_prompt1: .word prompt1
addr_prompt2: .word prompt2
addr_scantype: .word scantype
addr_hours: .word hours
addr_payrate: .word payrate

.global scanf
.global printf
```

Comment: Do you mean taking multiple inputs in a single `scanf` call, or just multiple calls as in the code here? It's also not clear exactly where you think this code is going wrong - "when I echo out R1, I receive a random value" echo out `r1` _at what point in the program_? The only time `r1` contains one of your numeric values is just before the call to `printf` - everywhere else it holds either pointers of garbage.

Comment: @Notlikethat Is it possible to take in multiple inputs using one scanf, and store those values in registers to be passed into a function? I am not quite sure how to do that at this point. And I am a little confused as to why R1 would contain garbage after I use scanf. With the call ldr r1,[r1], isnt that storing the value into the register from memory?

Comment: Well, the C compiler generates such assembly. ;-) As long as you follow the rules of the ABI, it should work like in C. You make a format string and give its address in one register (probably r0), then you give the addresses of the variables in other registers. If in doubt, you can probably write a piece of C code and then disassemble it with objdump (or generate list file with -Wa,-adhlns=file.lst if you are using Gnu tools) to see how C compiler does it.

Answer (score 0):

Since scanf places the retrieved data onto the stack; try loading the top of the stack value directly into a register for now. This is an alternative solution.

I was just trying to  use one scanf function to get values for multiple entries; in my case four (4). I'm still digging into the documentation; however, the code sample of the function below "simulates" getting multiple keyboard entries.

I just using four scanf calls; which, to me, is just a band-aid - but it works.

After the code are the program's results. Please note that I am entering one number at a time then pressing .

```
       .data 
scan0:  .string "%d"
.text
addr_scan:      .word   scan0
...


scan:
push {r0-r3,lr}
sub sp,sp, #4

ldr r0, addr_scan
mov r1, sp
bl scanf
ldr r9, [sp]            // store Ai

ldr r0, addr_scan
mov r1, sp
bl scanf
ldr r10, [sp]           // store Bi

ldr r0, addr_scan
mov r1, sp
bl scanf
ldr r11, [sp]           // store Ci

ldr r0, addr_scan
mov r1, sp
bl scanf
ldr r12, [sp]           // store Di

add sp, sp, #4


write:
push {r0-r3,lr}
ldr r0,=fmt3
mov r1, r9
mov r2, r10
mov r3, r11
push {r12}
bl printf
pop {r12}
pop {r0-r3,pc}
```

...

```
root@scw-cb8d4b:~/asm# ./sys_equations    
Enter A[1],B[1],C[1],D[1] values
12
23
34
45
You entered 12 23 34 45
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied and modified your code and it works.

The random number is likely an address that you are picking up from pointing r1 to the respective addr_... addresses vs sp. The randomness is likely due to address space layout randomization.

The output is at the bottom. You may need to adjust stack for larger values.

```
.data
string:         .asciz "Pay Rate: %d Hours: %d\n"
prompt1:        .asciz "Enter pay rate - round up to nearest dollar.\n"
prompt2:        .asciz "Enter hours.\n"
scantype:       .asciz "%d"
hours:          .word 0
payrate:        .word 0
.text
addr_prompt1:   .word prompt1
addr_prompt2:   .word prompt2
addr_scantype:  .word scantype
addr_hours:     .word hours
addr_payrate:   .word payrate

.global main
main:
push {LR}
sub sp, sp, #8

ldr r0, addr_prompt1    /*First param of printf */
bl printf               /*call printf */

ldr r0, addr_scantype   /* First param of scanf*/
mov r1, sp
bl scanf

ldr r4, [sp]
ldr r0, addr_prompt2
bl printf

ldr r0, addr_scantype
mov r1, sp
bl scanf

ldr r5, [sp]
ldr r0,=string
mov r1, r4
mov r2, r5
bl printf

add sp, sp, #8
pop {PC}
```

...

```
root@scw-cb8d4b:~/asm# ./jf
Enter pay rate - round up to nearest dollar.
100
Enter hours.
40
Pay Rate: 100 Hours: 40
```