# scanf and printf with floating point

Tags: assembly, arm, raspbian

So I've been following the "Raspbian Beginners" book by Bruce Smith, and have recently been working with floating points.  What I've been trying to accomplish is read in two floating points, multiply them, and print back their result.  I can read in and write one floating point fine, but when I try to do the second floating point it doesn't give me the number I read in, but instead an address (or at least what I think is an address).  Here is what I've done so far:

```
      .global main
      .func main

main:
      PUSH    {LR}
      SUB     SP,    SP,    #8
      LDR     R0,    addr_prompt1
      BL      printf

      LDR     R0,    addr_scantype
      MOV     R1,    SP
      BL      scanf

      VLDR    S14,   [SP]
      VCVT.F64.F32   D5,    S14

      LDR     R0,    addr_prompt2
      BL      printf

      LDR     R0,    addr_scantype
      MOV     R1,    SP
      BL      scanf

      VLDR    S18,   [SP]
      VCVT.F64.F32   D0,   S18

      LDR     R0,    addr_result
      VMOV    R1,    R2,   D5
      VSTR    D0,    [SP]
      BL      printf

      ADD     SP,    SP,   #8
      POP     {PC}

_exit:
      MOV     PC,    LR

addr_prompt1:       .word prompt1
addr_prompt2:       .word prompt2
addr_scantype:      .word scantype
addr_result:        .word result

     .data
prompt1:            .asciz "Enter first number: "
prompt2:            .asciz "Enter second number: "
scantype:           .asciz "%f"
result:             .asciz "YOur entered number is %f and %f.\n"
```

If I'm JUST printing floating points that are in my data section, I'm supposed to put my first one in registers R2 and R3 and the second one on the stack.  But for some reason, whenever I implement scanf I have to use registers R1 and R2 or else it won't print my first number correctly - and my second number will always come out wrong regardless of which registers I use.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this happens, and what I should do to make sure both of my numbers come back correctly?

Comment: I don't think you need to do addr_prompt1:       .word prompt1 addr_prompt2:       .word prompt2 Just the floating point address references.

Comment: I think your example is nearly the same as this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432455/reading-in-multiple-values-from-user-using-scanf-assembly-arm/33639093#33639093